# Newbie VPS and/or amazon ec2 question

Tags: hosting, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, vps

I have a basic but serviceable web hosting plan, but it doesn't support all the Java EE functionality I want to experiment with.

I've been thinking of signing up for some kind of VPS or Amazon ec2 service so I have a machine on the web that I can tinker with; that is, having direct control to install my own servers and databases and so on.

Where's a good inexpensive place to go to get started with a simple VPS system?  Or is ec2 the right place for me?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!
rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Instance Types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#instance)
[ec2 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing)

[Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/)
(If you have non trivial bandwidth/storage requirements, you will have to factor those into the price equation accordingly)

Yes, you will have "direct control to install your own software"

1. Is this a good place to start? - **yes**
2. Is this the best/cheapest available option? - **depends**
3. Does it give you direct control over the "machine"? - **yes**